# SQL Automatically converts 24 hour format time to 12 hour format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Time is visible on my table as follows

```
2017-09-15 16:30:00.000
```

And my Query is like this

```
Format(SlotStartTime,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mi:ss') as SlotStartTime
```

And this returns time like this

```
15/09/2017 04:30:00
```

So the calculation gets wrong it should be   `15/09/2017 04:30:00 PM` or stay as it is in 24-hour format. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hh` gives you 12 hour hours
`HH` gives you 24 hour hours

Also, `mi` is probably a typo, as it will return you a minute, followed by the letter `i`. Try this:

```
declare @datetime datetime = '2017-08-29 16:30:01'
select Format(@datetime,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') as SlotStartTime
```

You can find all valid datetime formatting characters here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 4):

`hh` is the code for 12 hour format.  `HH` is the code for 24 hour format.  It's similar to how `mm` (not `mi`) is for minutes and `MM` is for months.

You want:

```
FORMAT(SlotStartTime,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

12 hour with the time period:

```
FORMAT(SlotStartTime,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')
```